# How to test an email send in functional test?

Tags: email, testing, symfony, functional-testing

I'm writing functional test for my application, but I don't find how test mails are sent (like in sf 1.x). An tutorial exist on official doc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it through the profiler.

There is a cookbook explaining how you can use the profiler from your tests:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/profiling.html

The SwiftMailer should have its own entry in the profiler: `swiftmailer`